# How change build action from content to compile site wide

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to convert a asp.net website to asp.net web application. I need to change the build action for every file from "content" to "compile". How can i do this site width. I have a too many files to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually by editing .proj file, just replace Content with Compile. Here is an example:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5"><ItemGroup><Content Include="WebForm1.aspx" /></ItemGroup>

<Project ToolsVersion="3.5"><ItemGroup><Compile Include="WebForm1.aspx" /></ItemGroup>
```

Why you want to do this?

s